# Xcode - unidentified symbols for architecture archs in libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(opencore.o)

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, pjsip, opencore

I really having a hard time to figure out the problem.
i'm using `PJSIP` and also `opencore-amr.`

1. successfully compiled opencore-amr to arm64 (lipo -info told me)
2. successfully integrate opencore-amr (arm64) with PJSIP
   (arm64),configure it, make dep, make clean and make without any
   error.
3. when i try to compile it with XCode. it says

Undefined symbols for architecture `arm64`:
  "`_Decoder_Interface_Decode`", referenced from:
      `_amr_codec_decode` in `libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a(opencore_amr.o)`

4. I did `ar-t libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a` and the `opencore.o` inside the library is arm64.

I really have no clue to solve this.
please help me, thanks

FYI : I've tried open core with `pjsip` for android, and no issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the linker error, you probably forgot to link some library. Go to Project settings -> Build phases -> Link Binary with Libraries section and review it. Try to google which framework contains the classes mentioned in error log and then add it to frameworks list.